# Idempiere extend product model

Tags: java, idempiere

I want to create a class that extends the idempiere product model to create a code from other fields but I don't know which class I should import or what method I should override.

**org.compiere.model.MProduct:**

```
public MProduct (X_I_Product impP)
{
    this (impP.getCtx(), 0, impP.get_TrxName());
    setClientOrg(impP);
    setUpdatedBy(impP.getUpdatedBy());

    // Value field:
    setValue(impP.getValue());
    setName(impP.getName());
    setDescription(impP.getDescription());
    setDocumentNote(impP.getDocumentNote());
    setHelp(impP.getHelp());
    setUPC(impP.getUPC());
    setSKU(impP.getSKU());
    setC_UOM_ID(impP.getC_UOM_ID());
    setM_Product_Category_ID(impP.getM_Product_Category_ID());
    setProductType(impP.getProductType());
    setImageURL(impP.getImageURL());
    setDescriptionURL(impP.getDescriptionURL());
    setVolume(impP.getVolume());
    setWeight(impP.getWeight());
}   //  MProduct
```

Comment: I didn't get your point, did you created new columns in M_Product table and you want to make some vaildation on them, or you just want to extend the MProduct class and override some methods?

Comment: @YounesLAB I just want to extend the **MProduct** class and override the method that saves the "VALUE" column.

Comment: You can create new model class that inherited from MProduct class, then override the method you want to update, and If you want to link the Product window with your new class I think you need to add it in your model factory.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments, you clarified that your intent is to *"extend the MProduct class and override the method that saves the "VALUE" column"*.

To answer that, first let's define a simple version of `MProduct` class, with a few edits:

- it has only the `setValue()` method, since that's the only part relevant to your question (the other methods on `MProduct` are not relevant)
- the input parameter for `setValue()` was changed to `int` vs. the original type is in your example (whatever the return type is from `impP.getValue()`)

Here's a simple version of `MProduct`:

```
class MProduct {
    void setValue(int value) {
        System.out.println("setValue() on MProduct");
    }
}
```

Here's a simple class which extends `MProduct` by overriding the `setValue()` method:

```
class CustomProduct extends MProduct {
    @Override
    void setValue(int value) {
        System.out.println("setValue() on CustomProduct");
        // custom code goes here
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a simple example showing usage of both of the above classes (both `MProduct` and `CustomProduct`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CustomProduct().setValue(123);
    new MProduct().setValue(123);
}
```

And here's the output from running that example:

```
setValue() on CustomProduct
setValue() on MProduct
```